# PowerShell Closing open sessions

Tags: session, powershell

I'm working on a large script where I run a `Foreach` loop, define variables in that loop and afterwards check if the `$Server` variable is pingable and if it is remotely accessible.

For this I use the following functions coming from the PowerShell help:

```
# Function to check if $Server is online
Function CanPing ($Server) {
   $error.clear()
   $tmp = Test-Connection $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   if ($?) {
       Write-Host "Ping succeeded: $Server"; Return $true
   }
   else {
        Write-Host "Ping failed: $Server."; Return $false
   }
}

# Function to check if $Server is remotely accessible
Function CanRemote ($Server) {
    $s = New-PSSession $Server -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credentials -Name "Test" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($s -is [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]) {
        Enter-PSSession -Session $s
        Exit-PSSession
        Write-Host "Remote test succeeded: $Server."; Return $true
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Remote test failed: $Server."; Return $false
    }
}

# Execute functions to check $Server
if ($Server -ne "UNC") {

    if (CanPing $Server) {
        if (-Not (CanRemote $Server)) {
        Write-Host "Exit loop REMOTE" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        continue
        }
    }
    else {
         Write-Host "Exit loop PING" -ForegroundColor Yellow
         continue # 'continue' to the next object and don't execute the rest of the code, 'break' exits the foreach loop completely
    }
}
```

Every time when I run this code, there is a process created on the remote server called `wsmprovhost.exe`. This process represents the PowerShell session, if the info I found on the web is correct. However, when doing `Get-PSSession $Server` there are no open sessions displayed in the PowerShell ISE, even though the processes are visible on the remote server and can only be killed with the Task Manager.

When I run this code often the limit of open sessions is reached because every time a new process `wsmprovhost.exe` is added to the `$Server` and the command errors out. I've tried to solve this by adding `Exit-PSSession`to the code, but it doesn't close the session.

Any help or ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Enter-PSSession.  Enter-PSSession can only be used interactively, you can't use it in a script. I'd suggest something more like this:

```
# Function to check if $Server is remotely accessible
Function CanRemote ($Server) {

  Try {
   $s = New-PSSession $Server -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credentials -Name "Test" -ErrorAction Stop
   Write-Host "Remote test succeeded: $Server."
   $true
   Remove-PSSession $s
   }

  Catch {
          "Remote test failed: $Server."
          $false
        }
 }
```

Comment: The command `Remove-PSSession`does the trick, thank you for your advice. It's still strange to not be able to enter that remote session from within in a script, but this workaround is fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood correctly, Your remote `ps-session` are not getting closed.

To my understaning, `Get-PSSession` will show the session till your local session
is alive (I mean the session you created the remote `ps-session`) but once your local session
ends `Get-PSSession` will not show them cause they are no more live on your computer
rather on the remote system (or) they are no more in local session scope.

You can get the session using the command

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName server_name
```

If you want to remove them you can do like

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName server_name | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Rahul. I tried `Get-PSSession -ComputerName server_name` but it didn't give me any results, but the processes where still visible on the remote server. This was probably because, as you said, the local session was already closed when the script ended. I didn't think about this, as I expected to always see all open sessions when executing the command `Get-PSSession -ComputerName server_name`, but this is not the case apparently. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @DarkLite1, that's true; `Get-PSSession` will show the session only when they are live. Your are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Even After executing the below command also, if you are not able to create session

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName server_name | Remove-PSSession
```

Please, Restart the service Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) in the target machine.

Comment: Restarting the Windows Remote Management helps when the connection is refused due to a request process error. Thanks